# MongoDB Package Alias doesn't work for Laravel 5.2

Tags: mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, laravel-5

I want to use MongoDB Package for Laravel ... (Jenssegers)

I installed that, After I added Provide & Alias (config/app.php) ..., Then I put a MongoDB Driver for Laravel & put Default Driver in (config/database.php).

So, I wanted to test it. I created  a 'Post' Model & put these in that :

```
namespace App;
use Moloquent;

class Post extends Moloquent{
    protected $connection = 'Posts';
}
```

& In my controller I wrote these ... :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;
class WelcomeController extends Controller{
    public function getPosts() {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('welcome', compact('posts'));         
}}
```

I have done these from a tutorial ..., But I get this error :

ErrorException in AliasLoader.php line 66:

Class 'Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model' not found

Answer (score 0):

I guessed you were using the wrong namespace in the alias, the corrrect path is `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model`, you were missing the *Eloquent* part.